# Angular 6 - bootstrap carousel

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating carousel with bootstrap4 and images are coming from array. My problem is that first element must have the class `active`.

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let image of sliderImages" [ngClass]="image[0] ? 'active' : null">
      <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="image" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's your problem actually, can you explain what is wrong? Minimal but complete example whould help to answer that.

Comment: As I said, i need to set class .active to first element and later change this on prev next buttons, but i needed to do this with *ngFor directive, answer below is what I was looking for in 100%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your code to allow you to key in on the index of the ngFor objects.

```
<div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let image of sliderImages let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}">

  <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="image" alt="First slide">

</div>
```

Now you can key in on i to determine the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: pretty simple but i needed someone with fresh look on this :) Works perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure. I would mark it as answered so other people can find this solution more easily @JózefRzadkosz

Comment: Yup I have ban on 3 minutes left